# p:schedule - Wrap Text in Cells

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

How can I tell a PrimeFaces Schedule that I want the cells to have a fixed width, but span over multiple lines in case there is too much text inside (some kind of word wrap) ? Which css properties should I use, and where do I apply them?

This is the example I tried to use as a starting point (source: [HERE](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml))

**schedule.xhtml**

```
<h:form>
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

    <h:panelGrid columnClasses="value">
        <h3 style="margin-top: 0">Editable Schedule</h3>
        <p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{scheduleView.eventModel}" widgetVar="myschedule" timeZone="GMT+2">

            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{scheduleView.onDateSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />
            <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{scheduleView.onEventSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />
            <p:ajax event="eventMove" listener="#{scheduleView.onEventMove}" update="messages" />
            <p:ajax event="eventResize" listener="#{scheduleView.onEventResize}" update="messages" />

        </p:schedule>

        <h3>Locale Support ( Example: Turkish )</h3>
        <p:schedule id="scheduleLocale" value="#{scheduleView.eventModel}" locale="tr" />

        <h3>Lazy Schedule</h3>
        <p:schedule value="#{scheduleView.lazyEventModel}" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:dialog widgetVar="eventDialog" header="Event Details" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip">
        <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails" columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel for="title" value="Titles:" />
            <p:inputText id="title" value="#{scheduleView.event.title}" required="true" />

            <p:outputLabel for="from" value="From:" />
            <p:calendar id="from" value="#{scheduleView.event.startDate}" timeZone="GMT+2" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="to" value="To:" />
            <p:calendar id="to" value="#{scheduleView.event.endDate}" timeZone="GMT+2" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="allDay" value="All Day:" />
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="allDay" value="#{scheduleView.event.allDay}" />

            <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" />
            <p:commandButton id="addButton" value="Save" actionListener="#{scheduleView.addEvent}" oncomplete="PF('myschedule').update();PF('eventDialog').hide();" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>    
</h:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    PrimeFaces.locales['tr'] = {
        closeText: 'kapat',
        prevText: 'geri',
        nextText: 'ileri',
        currentText: 'bugün',
        monthNames: ['Ocak','Şubat','Mart','Nisan','Mayıs','Haziran',
            'Temmuz','Ağustos','Eylül','Ekim','Kasım','Aralık'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Oca','Şub','Mar','Nis','May','Haz',
            'Tem','Ağu','Eyl','Eki','Kas','Ara'],
        dayNames: ['Pazar','Pazartesi','Salı','Çarşamba','Perşembe','Cuma','Cumartesi'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Pz','Pt','Sa','Ça','Pe','Cu','Ct'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Pz','Pt','Sa','Ça','Pe','Cu','Ct'],
        weekHeader: 'Hf',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: '',
        month: 'Ay',
        week: 'Hafta',
        day: 'Gün',
        allDayText : 'Tüm Gün'
    };
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .value {
        width: 1000px;
    }
</style>
```

**ScheduleView.java**

```
package org.primefaces.showcase.view.data;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import org.primefaces.event.ScheduleEntryMoveEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.ScheduleEntryResizeEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultScheduleEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultScheduleModel;
import org.primefaces.model.LazyScheduleModel;
import org.primefaces.model.ScheduleEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.ScheduleModel;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ScheduleView implements Serializable {

    private ScheduleModel eventModel;

    private ScheduleModel lazyEventModel;

    private ScheduleEvent event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();
        eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Champions League Match", previousDay8Pm(), previousDay11Pm()));
        eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Birthday Party", today1Pm(), today6Pm()));
        eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Breakfast at Tiffanys", nextDay9Am(), nextDay11Am()));
        eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Plant the new garden stuff", theDayAfter3Pm(), fourDaysLater3pm()));

        lazyEventModel = new LazyScheduleModel() {

            @Override
            public void loadEvents(Date start, Date end) {
                Date random = getRandomDate(start);
                addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Lazy Event 1", random, random));

                random = getRandomDate(start);
                addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Lazy Event 2", random, random));
            }   
        };
    }

    public Date getRandomDate(Date base) {
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        date.setTime(base);
        date.add(Calendar.DATE, ((int) (Math.random()*30)) + 1);    //set random day of month

        return date.getTime();
    }

    public Date getInitialDate() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.FEBRUARY, calendar.get(Calendar.DATE), 0, 0, 0);

        return calendar.getTime();
    }

    public ScheduleModel getEventModel() {
        return eventModel;
    }

    public ScheduleModel getLazyEventModel() {
        return lazyEventModel;
    }

    private Calendar today() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DATE), 0, 0, 0);

        return calendar;
    }

    private Date previousDay8Pm() {
        Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
        t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
        t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) - 1);
        t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8);

        return t.getTime();
    }

    private Date previousDay11Pm() {
        Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
        t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
        t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) - 1);
        t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 11);

        return t.getTime();
    }

    private Date today1Pm() {
        Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
        t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
        t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 1);

        return t.getTime();
    }

    private Date theDayAfter3Pm() {
        Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
        t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 2);     
        t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
        t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 3);

        return t.getTime();
    }

    private Date today6Pm() {
        Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone(); 
        t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
        t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 6);

        return t.getTime();
    }

    private Date nextDay9Am() {
        Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
        t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
        t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 1);
        t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);

        return t.getTime();
    }

    private Date nextDay11Am() {
        Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
        t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
        t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 1);
        t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 11);

        return t.getTime();
    }

    private Date fourDaysLater3pm() {
        Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone(); 
        t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
        t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 4);
        t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 3);

        return t.getTime();
    }

    public ScheduleEvent getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(ScheduleEvent event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public void addEvent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if(event.getId() == null)
            eventModel.addEvent(event);
        else
            eventModel.updateEvent(event);

        event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
    }

    public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
        event = (ScheduleEvent) selectEvent.getObject();
    }

    public void onDateSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
        event = new DefaultScheduleEvent("", (Date) selectEvent.getObject(), (Date) selectEvent.getObject());
    }

    public void onEventMove(ScheduleEntryMoveEvent event) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Event moved", "Day delta:" + event.getDayDelta() + ", Minute delta:" + event.getMinuteDelta());

        addMessage(message);
    }

    public void onEventResize(ScheduleEntryResizeEvent event) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Event resized", "Day delta:" + event.getDayDelta() + ", Minute delta:" + event.getMinuteDelta());

        addMessage(message);
    }

    private void addMessage(FacesMessage message) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }
}
```

See picture below for an example. In the highlighted cell, I added the text: "This does not span over multiple rows".

[image]

Comment: isn't that default behaviour?

Comment: @Kukeltje I added a picture to the original question. It does not.

Comment: Then start using a browser developer tool. 'inspect' the node which contains the text that is not wrapped. See if some css is applied that might be related to wrapping. Try adding a new (temporary) rule in the browser developer tool, make it 'specific' enough and try setting alternative values for the wrapping css...

Comment: @Kukeltje I found the <table> tag and tried to add style="table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word;" to it - but it does not work

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes... I mentioned to inspect the node that contains the text. Always work from the inside out. And there is no table near that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using your link and a browser developer tool, I noticed this piece of html

```
<div class="fc-content">
   <span class="fc-time">1p</span> 
   <span class="fc-title">Birthday Party for my little boys' third birthday</span>     
</div>
```

An in the same browser developertool I saw the following CSS being applied

```
.fc-day-grid-event .fc-content {

    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

That explains everything... So making a more specific css selector (don't use !important), you can override this

```
.fc-day-grid-event .fc-content .fc-title{

    white-space: normal;

}
```

Comment: Worked on the example, and in my project also, thanks!

Comment: All basic html/css, nothing jsf/PrimeFaces specific. Please remember that for next/similar questions